# JRuby - loading resource from classloader failed

Tags: maven, jruby

I am running a `mvn install` goal with the plugin `gem-maven-plugin`, see below `pom.xml` -

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>de.saumya.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>gem-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>initialize</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The build is failing with the error message:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:2.0.1:initialize`

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: loading resource from classloader failed: META-INF/jruby.home/bin/gem`

I am building using Windows, but the software has been ported from Linux.

The file path `META-INF/jruby.home/bin/gem` does not exist on my system (it is a Unix/Linux path), is there a way to fix this error?

jRuby version: jruby 9.1.2.0

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a corrupted JRuby `.jar` file, copied from a corrupt repository.

Might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jelphy. You did.

I worked around it deleting my local repo after extending maven to download ruby gems directly from ruby repositories.

Add the following snippets to pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <!-- Allows us to download Ruby gems -->
            <!-- See https://github.com/jruby/mavengem -->
            <groupId>org.torquebox.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>mavengem-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    
     
  ********************************

  </build>
  
  ********************************
  <profiles>
  <profile>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>mavengems</id>
                <url>mavengem:https://rubygems.org</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>rubygems</groupId>
                <artifactId>sass</artifactId>
                <version>${sass.version}</version>
                <type>gem</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>rubygems</groupId>
                <artifactId>compass</artifactId>
                <version>${compass.version}</version>
                <type>gem</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
  </profile>
  </profiles>
```